# How to add custom authorization filter to method not controller in asp net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, attributes, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

When I add custom IAuthorization attribute to controller method it works, but when I add it to method that is not part of controller method, IAuthorization method does not execute. Why?

```
public interface ICasbinBLL
{
    public abstract string objectId { get; set; }

    [ClaimRequirement("userId", "delete")]
    string DeleteMonitoring();
}

public class CasbinBLL : ICasbinBLL
{
    public string objectId { get; set; }

    [ClaimRequirement("userId", "delete")]
    public string DeleteMonitoring()
    {
        return objectId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IAuthorizationFilter` is one of the filters in ASP.NET Core. Filters are executed by ASP.NET Core framework in [filter pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#how-filters-work).

> Filters run within the ASP.NET Core action invocation pipeline, sometimes referred to as the filter pipeline. The filter pipeline runs after ASP.NET Core selects the action to execute.

If you add filters to your own types, ASP.NET Core does not know how to execute them.

Comment: is there any way to make this process?

Comment: If you need to verify the claims on the current user, you could inject / pass the user or user validator into `DeleteMonitoring` method and verify the claims in the method. You could also inject / pass a generic validator which validates based on your custom attributes.

Comment: I know this way, is there any way to do this using attribute? but I must not use attribute in contoller, I should use it in the BLL layer or any other class method/

Comment: If you use attributes, then you are supposed to be invoking those attributes at appropriate time. ASP.NET Core framework won't do for you.

Comment: then the only way to solve this problem using attribute is that use attribute in controller action. Okay, thanks